# How to make layout vertically responsive

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I am creating a website page, which is responsive for both mobile and desktop versions.

Now, problem is, it shows proper layout in desktop as well as on websites like http://mobiletest.me/

But, when I actually open it in mobile (specially iPhone and internet explorer in Nokia Lumia), it shows wierd look! No style, no js nothing.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE?**

I just want that the table, should remain vertically and horizontally align at center. No matter it will be opened in any mobile or desktop version. Help needed!

```
Here is jsFiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/milindtheachiever/4hsd85kf/
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this without tables? They're usually a big pain to try and make responsive

Comment: Ya dude I know.. But Now I have to stick it to :(

Comment: Not to be a nag :p but any reason why?

Comment: Client requirement ;)

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle and it is showing as centered vertically and horizontally already.

Comment: @MilindBhatt - You actually have a client that requires you to use tables in the development??

Comment: @jamescampbell It is but once you move to mobile the right side is going to keep going to the right (from what I can tell from the jsfiddle) - he basically wants it to stay in the center as you resize the window. I've tried it before when I first started coding with tables but it was pretty much impossible to get it how I wanted to since tables require set sizes. Good luck to op tho

Comment: @DardanM ah i see, the body needs to have a width auto set then for the mobile css

Answer (score 1):

To align something in the centre of the screen regardless of the screen size use this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```